# Concatenating int and list in c#

Tags: c#, list, int, concatenation

I have an int list candidate key and an int randnumber, which has some value. For each of the candidatekey, I want to the add the randnumber.

How can do it? I tried this:

```
foreach (int l in candidatekey)    
{    
    candidatekey.Add( randnumber);   
}
```

Comment: Posting your code will make it way easier for us to locate the problem

Comment: This is just adding `randomnumber` to the list `candidatekey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add random number to every candidate key number. If that is the case try this.

```
var candidatekey = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
var randomnumber=42;

//we are using LINQ on list
candidatekey=candidatekey.Select(c => c+randomnumber).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks alot this is what i wanted